# Animación Jquery en Html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy intentando agregar de manera dinámica una clase en **css** que aplica un **BORDER** a un **span** que contiene un **INPUT** mediante Jquery y funciona, pero me gustaría que esta se haga con una transición suave y no de golpe como lo hace normalmente. Este es mi código Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(':text').focus(function(){
         $(MiSpan).addClass('i-seleccionado')
     })
 })
```

Al darle clic en el INPUT, me gustaría que el CSS del SPAN que lo contiene cambie pero de manera suave y no de golpe. Aprecio cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias!

Aquí una imagen de muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes usar una [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) de CSS pero sin ver el resto del código es un poco difícil darte una respuesta correcta :)

Comment: Jaja. Increible que no se me ocurrio antes. Gracias, ya lo conseguí!

Comment: [Publicalo como respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) por si alguien en el futuro tiene el mismo problema, recuerda siempre basarte en [answer] :)

Answer (score 2):

Veo que ya encontraste solución, sin embargo, por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema o duda aquí dejo el código:

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: border 0.8s;
}
div:hover{
  border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es siempre mejor práctica estilar clases y no elementos. Así que mi sugerencia es la siguiente. No sé por qué envuelves el elemento en un span pero de todas formas es irrelevante el elemento, cuando usas clases. De ahí a que sea mejor práctica.
Aqui te dejo el codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJqGej

HTML

```
<div class="input__wrapper">
  <label class="input__label">Elemento a dar foco:
    <input type="text" class="input__text isNotFocused" placeholder="dame foco!"></label>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // cashea los elementos para mejor performance
  var $input = $('.input__text'),
      $wrapper = $('.input__wrapper');
  function enfocame() {
    $input
      .removeClass('isNotFocused')
      .addClass('isFocused');
  }
  function desenfocame() {
    $input
      .removeClass('isFocused')
      .addClass('isNotFocused');

  }
  // usa delegacion de evento (event delegation) para mejor performance
  $wrapper
    .on('focus', '.input__text', enfocame)
    .on('blur', '.input__text', desenfocame);
});
```

CSS

```
.input__text {
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  outline: none;
}

.input__text.isFocused {  
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  transition: border .5s ease-out;
}

.input__text.isNotFocused {  
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  transition: border .5s ease-out;
}
```